# Does it make sense that the loss function for traning and evaluaton is different?

Tags: lasso, loss-functions, model-evaluation, train, huber

Huber loss function is widely used, because it combines the good properties of squared and absolute losses. Therefore, when I apply the penalized regressions, i.e. LASSO, Elastic net and Ridge, to make predictions, the Huber loss is used to tune the   hyperparameter by cross validation method in training process, and the  MAE or MSE is applied for evaluation in validation and test stages. In [Kolassa(2020)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207019301359?via%3Dihub), the author calims that it makes no sense that a model to be fitted by minimizing the in-sample MSE, but for holdout forecasts to be evaluated using the MAPE. (see the third point in Section 4 "Takeways").

So  my main question is - Does it make sense that I use Huber loss for training, but use other measures, such as MAE and MSE, to evaluate the forecasts?

Comment: Might this be helpful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470626/why-is-using-squared-error-the-standard-when-absolute-error-is-more-relevant-to/470786#470786

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks for your comment. This link  provides explict clarification for estimation loss and prediction loss.  What I concern is the mismatch of loss function in training and evaluation process. About this question, I have  looked  through a lot of answers in the  StackExchange website, but related answers are not that consistent.

Comment: According this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/518526/351802. The answerer thinks  the  measure for for fitting has nothing to do with the test measure.

Comment: It would be great to disambiguate as much as possible. Estimation loss and training loss are used as synonyms in my link. How does your definition of training loss differ from estimation loss? Are you perhaps referring to evolution loss in the validation phase vs. evaluation loss in the test phase?

Comment: I suggest *evaluation loss in the validation stage* and  *evaluation loss in the test stage*, I think these terms would be in line with most of the standard terminology. Regardless of which terminology you choose, consider editing your post accordingly. To answer your question briefly, I do not think it makes sense to use different losses in the two stages, so I guess I am in line with Kolassa (2020). But what motivates your question? What example do you have where this seems questionable or wrong?

Comment: For cross-validation in regression models, I think there should be three loss funcitons, the training loss (which I think equivalent to the estimation loss as your comment) in the tuning process, the evaluation loss  in the validation stage and  the evaluation loss for holdout forecasts (may be the test stage in your comment) .

Comment: I am still confused even after the edit. Cross validation *is* the validation stage. I have a hard time parsing phrases like *to tune the hyperparameter by cross validation method in training process* and *the training loss (which I think equivalent to the estimation loss as your comment) in the tuning process*.

Comment: It is also hard for me to express exactly... What I mean is for the cross-validation proceduce,  like a 8-fold  cross-validation , 7 subgroups are randomly used as training samples to estimate parameters, and the Huber loss is used to calculate training loss. Other one subgroup is used as  validation subsample, to calculate evaluation loss (i.e. MSE). After compeleting the  cross-validation proceduce, the hyperparameter is selected according to the minimum evaluation loss in validation stage. Using the selected hyperparameter, holdout forecasts are generated, and evaluated by  loss (i.e. MSE).

Comment: OK, so we have (i) training/estimation loss (Huber), (ii) evaluation loss in the validation stage (MSE) and (iii) evaluation loss in the test stage (MSE). I maintain that it makes little sense to choose different loss function for (ii) and (iii) but (i) can be different. A classical example is estimation of median of a normal distribution (corresponding to absolute loss) where the efficient estimator is the sample mean (square training loss), not the sample median (absolute training loss). Does that make sense? Does that contradict Kolassa's paper?

Comment: I tryed my best to express it clearly....So if according to last comment, the evaluation loss in validation stage and test stage (evaluate holdout forecasts) is the same, i.e. MSE, and the training loss is Huber loss. Then, in terms of the loss function, whether this situation makes sense?

Comment: OK, I guess I grasp your ideas. Thank you a lot! I will find out more about this question.

Comment: I have now checked the takeaway point #3 and do not think it is valid more generally than stated. (It may still be valid for MAPE which it focuses on.) Even so, I do not think one can claim (i) and (iii) must be equal. As I mentioned, there exist classical examples showing they need not be equal.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed  explanation very much. So you mean that the (ii) and (iii) should be the same, but the (i) not necessarily to be same with (ii) and (iii) ?  Then, how should I understand the point#3 in  Kolassa(2020),  I  don't quite understand your phrase "I have now checked the takeaway point #3 and do not think it is valid more generally than stated. (It may still be valid for MAPE which it focuses on.) "

Comment: I do not have time to read Kolassa (2020) in detail. What he says may well be right, but he is talking specifically about MSE vs. MAPE. However, it is not true that estimation loss must equal evaluation loss. If they were forced to be equal, inefficient estimators would have to be used, and forecast accuracy would be lower than without this restriction under the same fixed evaluation loss function.

Comment: ok, Thanks very much for your detaild and insightgul comment. Your answers really help resolve my confusion.